# SQL String Exclusion Condition not being applied

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently I have been trying to optimize a code I had for excluding certain character strings from a large set of data contained in an Oracle database. However I encounter issues with the conditions as those strings I am trying to exclude still appear.
A sample of the code looks like this:

```
WITH
    DUNS AS (
        select '%PERSON' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH0%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH1%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH2%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH3%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH4%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH5%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH6%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH7%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH8%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH9%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH-PERSON' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'TRIALACCT' as DUNS from DUAL
        ),
    ORGTYPE AS(
        select 'Do Not Assign' as ORGTYPE from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'HGBU_Store_DIM' as ORGTYPE from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'HGBU%' as ORGTYPE from DUAL
        ),
    CDQ AS(
        select 
            REGISTRY_ID, 
            NVL(DUNS,0) DUNS, 
            NVL(ORG_TYPE,0) ORG_TYPE, 
            NVL(TECH_ORG_TYPE,0) TECH_ORG_TYPE, 
            NVL(APPS_ORG_TYPE,0) APPS_ORG_TYPE
        from gtm_cdq a
        where not exists (select 1 from gtm_clean_accounts b where a.REGISTRY_ID=b.crm_registry_id)
        )
select * 
from CDQ g, DUNS h, ORGTYPE i
where g.DUNS not like h.DUNS
AND (g.ORG_TYPE not like i.ORGTYPE AND g.TECH_ORG_TYPE not like i.ORGTYPE AND g.APPS_ORG_TYPE not like i.ORGTYPE)
```

After this code runs successfully, I look at the results table and I see this:

```
REGISTRY_ID DUNS    ORG_TYPE    TECH_ORG_TYPE   APPS_ORG_TYPE   DUNS    ORGTYPE
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge     %PERSON   Do Not Assign
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge       PH0%    Do Not Assign
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge       PH1%    Do Not Assign
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge       PH2%    Do Not Assign
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge       PH3%    Do Not Assign
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge       PH4%    Do Not Assign
11803270    PHtola  HGBU_ge     HGBU_ge           HGBU_ge       PH5%    Do Not Assign
```

Is there something I am missing? I'm thinking it all comes from the last row (condition) that I specify the Org_Type columns to not contain the HGBU-type strings. Somehow, it doesn't get processed at all.
Any ideas?

Really appreciated!

Comment: For the sake of reproducing the issue it would be very helpful if you could add a WITH clause with a couple of rows of table gtm_clean_accounts and a WITH clause with some rows of gtm_cdq to your example code. Now we only see half the data.

Comment: Also, please don't use pictures - there are those of us who can't see them (e.g. firewall issues, screen-readers can't read them, etc.). Instead, update your question to include the data as text.

Comment: I have removed the image and added a table as per suggestion. I didn't realise some of you could not actually load the images. However I cannot share the source tables as they contain a very large amount of columns and data so I cannot figure how to include them in a relevant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your WHERE clause is not doing what you want or expect. Here's an even simpler example:

```
WITH
    DUNS AS (
        select '%A' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'B%' as DUNS from DUAL),
    CDQ AS(
    select 1 as registry_id, 'AA' as DUNS, 'a' as org_type,
        'a' as tech_org_type, 'a' as apps_org_type
        from dual
    )
select g.duns, h.duns
from cdq g, duns h
where g.duns not like h.duns;
```

Output:

```
g.duns h.duns
AA     B%
```

A join with a where clause will return all the rows from the (cartesian) join which don't match the where clause. In your example, if you try taking the where clause off, you'll see that it only adds a few more rows - ones with `i.DUNS = 'HGBU%'`

You need a NOT EXISTS instead of a join.

```
WITH
    DUNS AS (
        select '%PERSON' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH0%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH1%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH2%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH3%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH4%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH5%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH6%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH7%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH8%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH9%' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'PH-PERSON' as DUNS from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'TRIALACCT' as DUNS from DUAL
        ),
    ORGTYPE AS(
        select 'Do Not Assign' as ORGTYPE from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'HGBU_Store_DIM' as ORGTYPE from DUAL UNION ALL
        select 'HGBU%' as ORGTYPE from DUAL
        ),
    CDQ AS( -- I replaced the CDQ CTE with some dummy data so the query would run
        select 11803270 as registry_id, 'PHtola' as DUNS, 'HGBU_ge' as org_type,
            'HGBU_ge' as tech_org_type, 'HGBU_ge' as apps_org_type
            from dual
        )
select * 
from CDQ g
where not exists (select 1 from DUNS h where g.DUNS like h.DUNS)
  and not exists (select 1 from ORGTYPE i where g.ORG_TYPE like i.ORGTYPE)
  and not exists (select 1 from ORGTYPE i where g.TECH_ORG_TYPE like i.ORGTYPE)
  and not exists (select 1 from ORGTYPE i where g.APPS_ORG_TYPE like i.ORGTYPE)
;
```

Comment: Genius! Code seemed flawless in my head but seeing your answer I realized I was pretty far off. Tested and worked, super fast. Many thanks!!